# How to print toast on 2nd activity?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to print number of lines in toast. but it just puts me in the first activity again and again.

idk what I am doing wrong here.

The code is supposed to do like:
-> enter number in text box and it will print no. of lines in the toast on 2nd activity when the button in pressed.

code is like this:

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button obbtSend;
    private EditText obetMessage;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        obbtSend = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btSend);
        obetMessage = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etMessage);

        obbtSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openMainActivity();
            }
        });
    }

    public void openMainActivity(){
        String str = obetMessage.getText().toString();
        Intent obintent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        obintent.putExtra("var", str);
        this.startActivity(obintent);
    }
}
```

on the 2nd file:

```
package com.example.toastexample;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

public class MainActivity2 extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView obtvMsg;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        Intent ob = getIntent();
        String msg = "";
        String s = ob.getStringExtra("var").toString();
        int t = Integer.parseInt(s.toString());
        for(int i=1;i<=t;i++)
            msg=msg + "Hello World! \n";
        Toast.makeText(this,msg,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        obtvMsg = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvMsg);
        obtvMsg.setText(ob.getStringExtra("var").toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: The second parameter of `obintent` should be `MainActivity2.class` not `MainActivity.class`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't start the MainActivity2 but the MainActivity self again in openMainActivity(),

use code below to start the MainActivity2.

```
public void openMainActivity(){
        String str = obetMessage.getText().toString();
        Intent obintent = new Intent(this, MainActivity2.class);
        obintent.putExtra("var", str);
        this.startActivity(obintent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the destination activity as the Mainactitiy in which you are already

## Solution Code

```
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button obbtSend;
    private EditText obetMessage;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        obbtSend = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btSend);
        obetMessage = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etMessage);

        obbtSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openMainActivity();
            }
        });
    }

    public void openMainActivity(){
        String str = obetMessage.getText().toString();
        Intent obintent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity2.class);
        obintent.putExtra("var", str);
        startActivity(obintent);
    }
}
```

**Feel free to ask if something is unclear.**  And mark it as the correct answer if it helps you.

Comment: If it worked, then kindly upvote the answer.

Comment: bro I'm trying to upvote. but its not working. Maybe I'm new to stack overflow that's why.

Comment: @AkashNai no problem bro.